Error: "This request is not authorized to perform this operation" when using SASTokens to access Azure Storage Queues using Azure Storage SDK v12
I am using C# code like this (see below) to read/add/process Azure Storage queues using Storage SDK v12 and SAS Tokens. No matter what I change, I always have the same error: "This request is not authorized to perform this operation"
Context:
The storage account exists and I have Owner permissions on it.
The storage account does NOT have a firewall protecting it.
This same method works fine for blobs/container on the same storage account.
I can do whatever I want on the queues from the portal.
NOTE: this code (very similar) is filing in a production code that has no issue when using MSI (same SDK v12), and/or no SAS Tokens (but regular keys/connection string).
Code:
string queueName = "queue1";
string accountName = "<account_name>";
string storageKey = "<account_key>";
string endpointSuffix = "core.windows.net";
string connectionString = $"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={accountName};AccountKey={storageKey};EndpointSuffix={endpointSuffix}";

var options = new Azure.Storage.Queues.QueueClientOptions
{
    MessageEncoding = Azure.Storage.Queues.QueueMessageEncoding.Base64
};

Azure.Storage.Queues.QueueServiceClient serviceClient = new Azure.Storage.Queues.QueueServiceClient(
  serviceUri: new Uri($"https://{accountName}.queue.{endpointSuffix}"),
  credential: new Azure.Storage.StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, storageKey),
  options: options);

Azure.Storage.Queues.QueueClient client = serviceClient.GetQueueClient(queueName);

// client.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().Wait(); // **** This line works fine -when not commented-, no change in the storage account

var queueSasBuilder = new QueueSasBuilder
{
    ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(3)),
    QueueName = queueName
};

//  Defines the type of permission.
//var queueAccountPermissions = QueueAccountSasPermissions.Add | QueueAccountSasPermissions.Read | QueueAccountSasPermissions.Update | QueueAccountSasPermissions.Process;  //**** this fails the same way
//queueSasBuilder.SetPermissions(queueAccountPermissions);

var queuePermissions = QueueSasPermissions.Add | QueueSasPermissions.Read | QueueSasPermissions.Update | QueueSasPermissions.Process;
queueSasBuilder.SetPermissions(queuePermissions);

Uri sasUri = client.GenerateSasUri(queueSasBuilder);  // The client can generate the SasUri

Uri partialUri = new Uri($"{sasUri.Scheme}://{sasUri.Host}{sasUri.AbsolutePath}");
Console.WriteLine($"Successfully created SasToken storage queue for uri: '{partialUri}', expiration time: '{queueSasBuilder.ExpiresOn}'");

client = new Azure.Storage.Queues.QueueClient(queueUri: sasUri);
client.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().Wait();  // *** This line throws the exception

I have tried the following:

Uncommenting this line:

// client.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().Wait(); // **** This line works fine -when not commented-, no change in the storage account


and it works fine, i.e.: not using SAS tokens works

Uncommenting these two lines instead of using the QueueSasPermissions:

//var queueAccountPermissions = QueueAccountSasPermissions.Add | QueueAccountSasPermissions.Read | QueueAccountSasPermissions.Update | QueueAccountSasPermissions.Process;  //**** this fails the same way
//queueSasBuilder.SetPermissions(queueAccountPermissions);

It fails with the same error.

I added the RoleAssignment StorageQueueDataContributor for my principal. It fails the same way.



Error: "This request is not authorized to perform this operation" when using SASTokens to access Azure Storage Queues using Azure Storage SDK v12

To ensure the azure storage queue is created or not, you need to use the azure storage account sas in your code.
You can use the below code to create account sas token and check the azure queue is created or not and it sends message using Azure storage .Net SDK.
Code:
using Azure.Storage;
using Azure.Storage.Queues;
using Azure.Storage.Sas;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            await GetQueueSasToken();
            Console.WriteLine("SAS token generated and message sent successfully.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    public static async Task GetQueueSasToken()
    {
        // Storage account details
        string accountName = "venkat326123";
        string accountKey = "T3xxxxxw==";
        string queueName ="queue2";
        string sasToken = CreateAccountSasToken(accountName, accountKey);
        var serviceUri = new Uri($"https://{accountName}.queue.core.windows.net?{sasToken}");
        var queueServiceClient = new QueueServiceClient(serviceUri);
        await EnsureQueueExists(queueServiceClient, queueName);
        SendMessage(queueServiceClient, queueName);
    }
    public static string CreateAccountSasToken(string accountName, string accountKey)
    {
        var sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);
        // Create Account SAS
        AccountSasBuilder sasBuilder = new AccountSasBuilder
        {
            ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1), // Set expiration time
            Services = AccountSasServices.Queues,         // Enable queue service
            ResourceTypes = AccountSasResourceTypes.Service | AccountSasResourceTypes.Container | AccountSasResourceTypes.Object, 
        };

        // Set permissions for queue operations
        sasBuilder.SetPermissions(AccountSasPermissions.Add | AccountSasPermissions.Create | AccountSasPermissions.Read | AccountSasPermissions.Write);
        string sasToken = sasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(sharedKeyCredential).ToString();
        return sasToken;
    }

    public static async Task EnsureQueueExists(QueueServiceClient queueServiceClient, string queueName)
    {
        var queueClient = queueServiceClient.GetQueueClient(queueName);
        var createResult = await queueClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
        if (createResult != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Queue '{queueName}' created.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Queue '{queueName}' already exists.");
        }
    }

    public static void SendMessage(QueueServiceClient queueServiceClient, string queueName)
    {
        var queueClient = queueServiceClient.GetQueueClient(queueName);
        queueClient.SendMessage("Hello, Azure Queue with SAS!");
        Console.WriteLine("Message sent successfully.");
    }
}

Output:
Queue 'queue2' already exists.
Message sent successfully.
SAS token generated and message sent successfully.


Reference:
Create an account SAS with .NET - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn

Thanks for the answer (I am testing it).
-Q: Does this means that in order to check the existence of queue, I need to get a SAS for the service?
-Q: In what cases would the QueueSasBuilder and QueueSasPermisions be used?

Operation in queues which can be used.

The proposed change worked fine.  Thanks a lot for your answer!
With this change I can do all I need with queue, and since the goal with this change is to have a token with an expiration date, no further action is needed, i.e.: I will use this code.

Glad to know it worked for you.
